# Regra para redirecionamento com parâmetros

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess

Estou tentando montar um sistema de URL's amigáveis porem estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma página que possui uma lista com vários itens. A pagina tem essa URL:

```
http://localhost/personal/portifolio
```

Quando o usuário acessa um desses itens, é redirecionado para:

```
http://localhost/personal/projeto?id=2
```

Gostaria que a URL ficasse assim:

```
http://localhost/personal/projeto/nome-do-projeto
```

Tenho regras de URLs que funcionam bem, mas essa não esta dando certo:

```
#codigo produtos não funciona    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} != ""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[(0-9)]$
RewriteRule ^projeto/[(a-zA-Z0-9)+]/[(0-9)+]/?$ /projeto?id=$2&title=$1 [NC]
```

O parâmetro é passado assim:

```
<a href='".$_url."projeto?id=".$portifolio['id']."&tittle=".$portifolio['tittle']."'>`
```

em `$_url` tem `http://localhost/personal/`.

Comment: Hebert, se puder, dê uma espiadinha no histórico de edições, para ver como formatar uma postagem. Aqui tem uma ajuda mais avançada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depois de estudar algumas semanas expressões regulares, consegui:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^projeto/(.*)$ projeto.php?$1
```

e o `href` eu passo assim: 
 `<a href='".$_url."projeto?".$portifolio['tittle']."'>`

único problema é, que tem um `?` ali no meio, funciona se eu coloco `/` porem na pagina não carrega as imagens... preciso mudar o caminho de `./` para `../`se alguém puder complementar agradeço! =)

Answer (score 2):

Já faz um bom tempo que não uso regras de reescrita de Apache, mas na sua regra você está montando a URL com id e title, mas a URL que você gostaria de obter só tem o título, então a sua regra também só pode ter o título para funcionar.

Outra coisa é que o title está com um "t" a mais no seu HTML. Também o operador de concatenação de strings foi usado de forma errada.

E quando você acessar a URL deve ser a URL definitiva e não com os parâmetros, ou seja, ao invés de

```
<a href='".$url."projeto?id=".$portifolio['id']."&tittle=".$portifolio['title']."'>
```

seria

```
<a href="$url" . 'projeto/' . $portifolio['title']>
```

Comment: escrevi assim mesmo para diferencia do atributo `title` do html, esse `tittle` é porque vem do banco rs, mas para utilizar a essa url, como dete estar o `.htaccess`?

Comment: Você já tentou deixar só a parte do título na regra, como eu sugeri?

Comment: sim já tinha tentado, da erro 500 =/